# C++ how to create a search path for a header file

Tags: c++, header, include, search-path

I am making a C++ project where I want to be able to include the header file with angular brackets. I have seen people do this from IDE's, is it possible to do this from the terminal?

Comment: Depends on the compiler. In gcc/clang, the option is called "-I /path/to/include/dir".

Comment: Maybe useful: [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include “filename”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename). Dispite the title, it has some good info related to this question (I believe).

Comment: @PhilippClaßen Is this command used like ```g++ -Idirectory```?

Comment: @MaximV Exactly. However, some clarification as I just see it. You will not have to use <>, but you can use "" then. <> should be reserved for system libraries.